# How to view embedded PDFs on a website in Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: ubuntu, internet

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 and have tried 3 different browsers (Chrome, Firefox, Chromium) to open an embedded pdf file ("application/pdf") and none of them seem to work.

On Chrome I've installed the Adobe PDF viewer plugin, but when the PDF pops-up I still get a "Couldn't load plug-in" error with a grey background.

How can I view embedded PDFs on Ubuntu 14.04?

Any browser/plug-in combination will do, so long as I don't need to change my OS.

Answer (score 0):

Chrome has a builtin PDF-Viewer, so you don't have to install the Adobe plugin.

See under `chrome://plugins/` whether "Chrome PDF Viewer" is activated.

Comment: yep, Chrome PDF Viewer always allowed ;(

Comment: @JodkaLemom I'm getting that message, so the plug-in isn't being loaded for some reason, i know that the div is object (<object></object>) in the html

Comment: http://forums.asp.net/t/1877403.aspx?Issue+with+embedded+pdf+object+in+chrome+browsers says Chrome does not understand embedded PDFs in an object tag, only in an iframe.

Comment: You could deactivate the Chrome PDF Viewer and see whether the Adobe plugin takes over.

Comment: sounds like it is the Object tag itself like in the link you posted, have you been able to get an Object containing a PDF to render on Ubuntu? if so, what browser/plug-in did you use?